# how to make the progression of a progressbar swing?

Tags: java, swing, concurrency, event-dispatch-thread, jprogressbar

I would like to creat an apllication that install  files in  devices. but i have a problem to implement the progress, the code that i use in my fram to call the class to install is given below, execShellCmd is the method called to install to all devices. value is a static value gived by the Install class. i would like to implement a progressbar relited to install and value in order to give the progression of installation.

```
private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
     Thread t;  
        t = new Thread(){   
        private int postion;
     public void run(){  
        Install install = new Install();
        int position = 0;
        String fileName = directory;
        String shellCommand = fileName;

       // for (int position =0; postion < 105;position +5) {
                jProgressBar1.setValue(Install.value);
                try {
                        Thread.sleep(500);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                }
                position += 5;
        //}
        install.execShellCmd(shellCommand);
        //jTextArea1.setText(error.err.toString());
        }

        };
        t.start();
    }
```

Comment: The [progress bar tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/progress.html) would be a good place to start

Comment: i started with tuto, but it isn't the problem to create a loop method; to progress the bar, but how to relat the bar to the installation methode that execute a script. or if i use indeterminate mode how to stop animation

Comment: Don't update UI components outside of the EDT context. Use SwingWorker instead of thread

Answer (score 2):

As shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15121864/230513), you can use `ProcessBuilder` to execute your script. Parse the combined streams, obtained from `getInputStream()`, to assess the script's actual progress. Use that information to condition your [`JProgresBar`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/progress.html). To preserve liveness in the GUI, do this in the `doInBackground()` method of a [`SwingWorker`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html), from which you can invoke `setProgress()`.

Comment: that is what i am doing in the Install class, and the number of line gived as a result of my script is gived by the static variable value

Comment: because when i call this value i will have juste the last value in the end of the execution

Comment: Right, a single value isn't very helpful; you have to parse the script's `stdout` stream. Is it your script? Can you enable something like verbose mode? Edit: Please update your question to reflect your approach.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm... it is said this thread approach is not suitable for JProgressBar. Instead, move with `Timer`. I have had the same issue while trying to work with JProgressBar, inside threads. Use the following link for more info, it has working example as well:

http://www.coderanch.com/t/566728/GUI/java/JProgressBar-Napkin-feel-working

And yes, look at my answer in the following:

[What is the ways updating jProgressBar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10587931/what-is-the-ways-updating-jprogressbar)